# Как вернуть программу на начало ввода Python

Tags: python

Недавно я начал изучать Python и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Например на простой программе

```
print('Эта программа создана для конвертации мегабайт в гигабайты и обратно')
print('1.-конвертация мегабайт в гигабайты')
print('2.-конвертация гигабайты в мегабайты')
z=int(input('Введите номер задания '))
if z == 1:
    m=float(input('Введите количество мегабайт '))
    g=int
    g=m/1024
    print(g)
elif z==2:
    g=float(input('Введите количество гигабайт '))
    m=int
    m=g*1024
    print(m)
else:

input('Press to close programm ')
```

Как сделать так чтобы после вывода конвертированного числа пользователь мог вернуться к началу выбора задания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните весь код в функцию, например, `convert`, запустите её 1 раз, а потом в цикле спрашивайте пользователя, хочет ли он запустить код ещё раз (или вовсе не спрашивайте). В зависимости от ответа вызывайте её или завершайте программу:

```py
def convert():
    z=int(input('Введите номер задания '))
    if z == 1:
        m=float(input('Введите количество мегабайт '))
        g=int
        g=m/1024
        print(g)
    elif z==2:
        g=float(input('Введите количество гигабайт '))
        m=int
        m=g*1024
        print(m)


print('Эта программа создана для конвертации мегабайт в гигабайты и обратно')
print('1.-конвертация мегабайт в гигабайты')
print('2.-конвертация гигабайты в мегабайты')

convert()
while True:
    flag = input('Ещё раз? [да/нет]: ')

    if flag == 'да':
        convert()
    else:
        break
```

**UPD:**
Ваш код написан не в *Pythonic-style* :). Как минимум, Вам не следует делать `g=int`, `m=int`:

```py
def convert():
    z = int(input('Введите номер задания: '))
    if z == 1:
        m = float(input('Введите количество мегабайт: '))
        g = m / 1024
        print(g)
    elif z == 2:
        g = float(input('Введите количество гигабайт: '))
        m = g * 1024
        print(m)


print(
    'Эта программа создана для конвертации мегабайт в гигабайты и обратно' '\n'
    '1 - конвертация мегабайт в гигабайты' '\n'
    '2 - конвертация гигабайты в мегабайты' '\n'
)

convert()
while True:
    flag = input('Ещё раз? [да/нет]: ')

    if flag == 'да':
        convert()
    else:
        break
```