# Простейший калькулятор, возврат к середине программы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок, и пытаюсь все больше добавить функций в простейший калькулятор в python 3.
Прежде чем задать вопрос, я попытался найти инфо сам, даже на англоязычных форумах, возможно не ту команду ищу.
Сам вопрос:
Хочу после того как пользователь увидел ответ, программа спрашивала не хочет ли он еще? Например

```
again = input("Хочешь еще? ")
if (again == "Да" or again == "да")
```

Калькулятор возвращался к строке с выбором символа. Как это сделать?
Код с середины т.к. до этого идет обычная беседа с пользователем:

```
Calc = input("Хочешь попробовать мой Калькулятор?  ")
if (Calc == "Да" or Calc == "да"):
    What = input("Выбери что хочешь сделать: +, -, * или /  ")
    if (What == "+"):
        a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
        b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
        c = a + b
        print("Надеюсь правильно:"  + str(c))
    elif (What == "-"):
        a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
        b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
        c = a - b
        print("Надеюсь правильно:"  + str(c))
    elif (What == "*"):
        a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
        b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
        c = a * b
        print("Надеюсь правильно:"  + str(c))
    elif (What == "/"):
        a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
        b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
        c = a / b
        print("Надеюсь правильно:"  + str(c))
    else:
        print ("Не поняла")
elif (Calc == "Нет" or Calc == "Не" or Calc == "нет" or Calc == "не"):
    print("Ну и ладно, пойду поем")
else:
        print ("Не поняла")
```

Благодарю заранее!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть программу на начало ввода Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990788/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял смысл вопроса - как продолжить выполнение цикла или прервать его. В Python, как правило, используется нечто вроде:

```
while True:
     cont = input("Продолжаем работу?")
     # Здесь как-то превращаем ответ пользователя в логическое значение v
    if v:
         # Выполняем работу
         continue # И возвращаемся в начало цикла
    else:
         break # Завершаем выполнение цикла
```

Comment: Спасибо!
В этом случае программа бесконечно спрашивает Продолжить ли работу и не возвращается к предыдущему циклу
Может я совсем не так что-то делаю?

Comment: @Евгений - *не возвращается к предыдущему циклу* - что такое **предыдущий**  цикл?! В коде, который вы привели только один цикл.  Вы можете чётко сформулировать, что Вы желаете получить? Сдаётся мне, что если вы запишите на листочке бумаги (чётко!!!) желаемое поведение программы, то и ответ сразу станет очевидным.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
def a_b():
    a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
    b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
    return a, b

calc = input("Хочешь попробовать мой Калькулятор? (Any_key+Enter или Enter-выход) ")

while calc:
    print()
    a, b = a_b()

    What = input("Выбери что хочешь сделать (+, -, * или /) :  ")

    if (What == "+"):
        c = a + b
    elif (What == "-"):
        c = a - b
    elif (What == "*"):
        c = a * b
    elif (What == "/"):
        c = a / b
    else:
        c = ""
        What = " ? Не понятная операция ? "

    print("\n{} {} {} = {}".format(a, What, b, c))    

    calc = input("\nХочетите продолжить? (Any_key+Enter или Enter-выход) ")
```

---

Update

```
def a_b():
    a = float(input("Введи первое число:  "))
    b = float(input("Введи второе число:  "))
    return a, b

calc = input("Хочешь попробовать мой Калькулятор? (Enter или `нет`-выход) ")

while calc != 'нет':
    print()
    a, b = a_b()

    What = input("Выбери что хочешь сделать (+, -, * или /) :  ")

    if (What == "+"):
        c = a + b
    elif (What == "-"):
        c = a - b
    elif (What == "*"):
        c = a * b
    elif (What == "/"):
        c = a / b
    else:
        c = ""
        What = " ? Не понятная операция ? "

    print("\n{} {} {} = {}".format(a, What, b, c))    

    calc = input("\nХочетите продолжить? (Enter или `нет`-выход) ")
```

Comment: Скорее бы 3.8..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, видимо, совсем не понимаю как тут все работает в этом коде, но не совсем то, что хотел получить в итоге. Программа возвращает цикл, но немного не туда, куда хотелось бы попытаюсь понять как его доделать

Comment: То есть тут выходом будет Enter, я пытаюсь сделать чтобы выходом стал пользовательский ввод "Нет" 
Подскажите, возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: @Евгений я добавил обновление